# Delete in CRUD is not working. knex.js, mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, api, crud, knex.js

I am not so experienced with js and js packages. I have been trying to make crud api using node.js, knex.js ... and mysql.
I have successfully created Create, Read, and Update, but i cannot delete item by id. Hope, you can help me.

> This is my routing file.

```
const Router = require("koa-router");
const { insertClient, allClient, updateClient, deleteClient } = require("../db/queries/clients");
const router = new Router();
const BASE_URL = `/api/v2/clients`;
...
...
router.delete(`${BASE_URL}/delete/`, async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const id = ctx.request.body
    const del = await deleteClient(id)
    ctx.body = del
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

> And this is my query file.

```
const knex = require("../connection");
const { where } = require("../connection");
...
...
function deleteClient(id){
  return knex("clients").where({"clients.id": id}).del()
}
```

I want to delete an item by id from db, using raw json request on postman like this

```
{
"id":2
}
```

Comment: You have to execute your query In your deleteClient function. https://knexjs.org/#Builder-del%20/%20delete

Comment: @Andrea I guess i am doing so, in here

Comment: ```return knex("clients").where({"clients.id": id}).del()```

Comment: I assume you have checked the id to be correct, right? I think it would be better not to mix db access logic between controller and DAL functions. Start and end your db transaction inside your deleteClient function, it is not clear otherwise, and NOT use del as a variable name.